# chemical reactions

Tags: chemfig, chemmacros

I would like to reproduce the same as this picture using the `chemfig` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor} %insertion d'images
\usepackage{titlesec}
\graphicspath{{Annexes/images/}} %directory of the images
\usepackage{lipsum} %paragraphes prédéfinis
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} %decoration des en tetes
\usepackage[sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{usnomencl}%pour la nomenclature
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\setchemrel{1pt}{}{6em}
\textbf{Sc\chemrel[\footnotesize hnu]{<->}e$^{-}_{CB}$ \chemsign+ h$^{+}_{VB}$}\\
\setchemrel{1pt}{}{6em}
\textbf{A$_{ads}$\chemsign+ e$^{-}_{CB}$ \chemrel[\footnotesize hnu]{->}A$^{{•}-}_{ads}$}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to use `chemfig` for this? Both `mhchem` and `chemformula` (which you implicitly load through `chemmacros`) are much better suited for those kind of reactions...

Comment: As a note; This would be trivial to create with `[chemmacros](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en)` and `[chemformula](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula)`

Comment: @clemens can you guide me a little more? if you can just help me for the first line. Thank you

Comment: I will post an answer in a bit. Out of curiosity: what does `h` in the reaction stand for?

Comment: h for holes of the valence electron

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to typeset the reactions with `chemfig`. It is an excellent package for drawing skeletal formulae of organic compounds. However, the reactions in your example are much easier typeset with `mhchem` or `chemformula`. The latter is loaded by `chemmacros` so you already have it available.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \setchemformula{charge-hshift=0pt}
  % \sffamily % uncomment if you want or need the following to be sans serif
  \ch{ Sc ->[$h\nu$] e_{CB}- + h_{VB}+} \\[1ex]
  \ch{A_{ads} + e_{CB}- -> @{charge-hshift=-.15em} A_{ads}^{*-}} \\[1ex]
  \ch{D_{ads} + h_{VB}^+ -> D_{ads}^{*+}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway, if you insist on using `chemfig` you should read what it writes in the log file and follow the advice:

> Package chemfig Warning: the macro `\chemrel` is deprecated. Please,
>   build schemes with `\schemestart` and inside, use `\arrow`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for \text

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \schemestart
    Sc
    \arrow{->[$h\nu$]}
    $\mathrm{e}_{\text{CB}}^- + \mathrm{h}_{\text{VB}}^+$
  \schemestop\\[1ex]
  \schemestart
    $\mathrm{A}_{\text{ads}} + \mathrm{e}_{\text{CB}}^-$
    \arrow
    $\mathrm{A}_{\text{ads}}^{*-}$
  \schemestop\\[1ex]
  \schemestart
    $\mathrm{D}_{\text{ads}} + \mathrm{h}_{\text{VB}}^+$
    \arrow
    $\mathrm{D}_{\text{ads}}^{*+}$
  \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using sans serif font for the reactions is possible and for the `chemformula` version only requires to set the surrounding text font to sans serif. In the `chemfig` version it requires a little bit more work.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what i was looking for BUT :) that "star" * should be a point, everything is nice except that dot (the dot means a free electron)
thanks  @clemens

Comment: Please have a look at the `chemformula` package's manual and especially the section about Kroeger-Vink notation.